# django-login-required-middleware WSGI error

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I'm trying to apply this way to my project :

http://onecreativeblog.com/post/59051248/django-login-required-middleware

Here is my `settings.py`:

```
...

LOGIN_URL = '/admin/login/'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'project.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]

...
```

and here my `middleware.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from re import compile

EXEMPT_URLS = [compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [compile(expr) for expr in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    """
    Middleware that requires a user to be authenticated to view any page other
    than LOGIN_URL. Exemptions to this requirement can optionally be specified
    in settings via a list of regular expressions in LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS (which
    you can copy from your urls.py).

    Requires authentication middleware and template context processors to be
    loaded. You'll get an error if they aren't.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user'), "The Login Required middleware\
 requires authentication middleware to be installed. Edit your\
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert\
 'django.contrib.auth.middlware.AuthenticationMiddleware'. If that doesn't\
 work, ensure your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting includes\
 'django.core.context_processors.auth'."
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
            if not any(m.match(path) for m in EXEMPT_URLS):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

I put that `middleware.py` on my project root.

```
project
|__db.sqlite3
|__manage.py
|__middleware.py
|__app
   |___admin.py
   |___views.py
   |___models.py
```

but I got an error.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 
'project.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing 
module: 'No module named 'project.middleware'
```

Comment: That blog post is from 2008, so the middleware class is not going to work with modern versions of Django. If you search you may find that somebody else has already written a suitable login required middleware for Django 1.10+. Otherwise,  see the [middleware docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/) for how to write middleware classes that work with the `MIDDLEWARE` setting.

Comment: so that will not going work on future?

Comment: No, that middleware won't work with the new `MIDDLEWARE` setting in Django 1.10+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `project` directory (the one including `manage.py`) is on the python path. Therefore you shouldn't include the `project.` prefix for modules in that directory.

Change your `MIDDLEWARE` setting to:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: its work, but got new error `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

Comment: As I said in the comments above, that blogpost is written for an old version of Django so the middleware isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `login_required` decorator instead a middleware. Because the middleware will be executed for each and every request. So, just decorate the view with `login_required` decorator.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def user_detail(request):
    # some code
```